# Does a well explained question nullify a "no research effort" downvote?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

First let's start with my understanding of what `"this question does not show any research effort"` means, because if my understanding is wrong then this question is probably invalid:

As I understand it, "no research effort" basically means that the OP has not given any indication they have tried to solve the problem for themselves before asking the question. Correct?

Next, take [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797806/linq-query-to-merge-distinct-items-in-a-list). The question is well written and describes the objectives perfectly, with examples of data and models. However, there is nothing what-so-ever to indicate they have tried to look for a solution themselves (either via research or by attempting some code). Yet, the question already has a large number of upvotes.

So, should the question be rewarded (as it has been so far), or should it be downvoted (as I did)?

Imagine the question that I linked didn't have any sample data or code, would it still have the upvotes? Personally I think it would have a lot more downvotes, so what I am asking is: why has this question been so popular just because it is a "pretty" version of a "this is what I want, now do it for me" question?

Comment: I use it slightly differently, mostly when a question *could have been answered by* research that the OP obviously didn't do. A question that's really non-trivial that doesn't contain the details of the research they did is not ideal, but it's not bad either.

Comment: I have no doubt the OP could have gotten somewhere via research, even just to the point of "I was thinking of grouping but it's not quite working how I want...".

Comment: I think the question was well asked, and as such am upvoting it. The question provided everything we need to solve the OP's problem.  Some users downvote because they want you to research the problem, find the answer, and then never ask it on Stack Overflow. Of course, if everyone did that, there'd be no Stack Overflow. Downvoting says "Don't do whatever you just did."In this case, the question is 'useful', and should be upvoted.

Comment: @musefan What would the purpose of that particular excerpt be though? Would it provide any more value to the question? Perhaps the OP just (*IMO correctly*) identified that adding something like that wouldn't raise the quality of their question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker; I am not arguing the usefulness, or indeed the good formatting, but more a case of why this bypasses the need to research the problem. I guess overall, I am asking: are we accepting "no research" questions as long as the OP makes them look nice?

Comment: @DonkeyKong: It wouldn't make it more useful, and I fully agree that it's useful question as it is, but are we not being a bit contradicting by praising this question, yet downvoting any other question that doesn't show research effort? We demand effort from other users/questions, so why not this one too?

Comment: @musefan: If it would be useful (and thus deserving an upvote) but it also lacks research effort (and thus might deserve a downvote), those cancel out, do they not?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: hmmm, that's certainly a good point! (though not proven by current up/down vote ratio). Why don't you make it an answer and suggest that the approach should be to NOT VOTE due to conflicting reasons? (see how people feel about that)

Comment: @musefan: I'm not going to even *try* to explain extant voting patterns, only those I think make sense. ;)

Comment: This whole discussion just seems kind of pointless to me (*no offense*). People can vote however they want, and in this case it appears that many people found this question well asked and interesting. If ***you*** highly value an explicit mention of effort, like to assign values to positive and negative qualities of the question, sum them (`+1-1=0`), and vote accordingly, then do so! I don't see why a voting approach needs to be outlined for a case like this.

Comment: It's much easier to downvote a shitpost than a well-written one - because with the former you have absolutely no reason to upvote it but *every reason to downvote it*. In fact, I would choose to downvote a post even if it demonstrates research, if it is so poorly-presented as to not be worth my time either editing or answering ([unless the topic is so obscure that even *that* trumps how badly-written it is, because *it cannot be researched*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27506735/revisions)).

Comment: @musefan Some of the best questions on Stack Overflow are no research questions.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Indeed they are, though the majority I see are from times long past where people didn't care so much about such things (just gotta get the site filled up, right?)

Comment: A well-written post on the other hand is miles better than a poorly-written one, because even if the OP didn't take the time to research the topic, at least they took the time to make the question accessible and presentable (i.e. what @George said), which is something the vast majority of askers *don't bother with* - whether you like it or not, such questions are a rarity on Stack Overflow and IMO shouldn't be neglected.

Comment: As for the tooltips on the voting arrows? I don't really bother with them. Or should I say - I don't follow them strictly to the letter. Research effort is *great*, but not entirely necessary depending on the question.

Comment: OP here. While it's nice to say "this is what I've researched", for this question while I looked at GroupBy, I could not work out how to fit it to my use case. You can see by the answers provided that the result requires a fairly sophisticated knowledge of Linq, especially coming from my perspective of someone with little knowledge in this area.  Secondly, the question was downvoted because there was a similar question related to VB.NET, which did not show up in my search, and I would have dismissed as they different LINQ syntaxes.

Comment: OP here part 2 - Finally, a shame that future people searching for this question will dismiss it due to the down votes as it's a nice compact question with a clear deliverable that was answered really well and I think would be a good resource for others in my position. The question had 10 upvotes at one point, so others obv thought it helpful

Comment: @Evonet: Might just be me, but if I was looking for a solution to a problem I would not care what the question score is, I would still look at the answers as they are the important part

Comment: there are 2 types of ppl in SO, the ones that wanna help and the others that just wanna downvote and close.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: Don't forget those that just want to make pointless comments

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: Downvoting and closing _is_ helping, just like answering.

Comment: musefan: self critique? Josh Caswell: no it's not, you tell me when you felt helped with a close or a downvote.

Comment: Related: [shog9's answer to "_Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/11107541), and ["_How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you feel there was a lack of research in that question, and it is simply a give me teh codez question, then by all means downvote. That is your prerogative.

I really do dislike questions of this type. I believe the popular term for them is *gimme teh codez*. However, there are always exceptions and this one is right on the border of it; that is probably why there is a controversial set of votes up and down.

This question provides enough context, background, and clarity, to be answered very easily. As such, it has gone far enough to attempt to not waste any time of the answerer. I believe that when an OP makes enough effort to not waste the time of users answering their question, that it goes over very well and that is probably why it received the answers and upvotes.

So the upside is that it is easily answerable, doesn't require a long answer, and provided enough context that it was good to go on its first version.

The downside is that this question really is a gimme teh codez question regardless of how well it is posed. As a result, a code only answer was given with no explanation of what is going on. It also kind of plays into the broken window cliche, where other users will see this and *potentially* (this may be a stretch, and I am not sold on this premise entirely), potentially think that they can also pose gimme teh codez questions and get quick answers with working solutions.

Overall, this question does not seem to be egregious to me and I also do not think it is doing harm. I also see your point of downvoting it as looking up how to do this should have been rather trivial.

I don't think taking this one question and going forward with downvoting every question asking for linq would be fair though, and would encourage you to vote based on content on a case to case basis.

Comment: Yeah, I think one of the reasons I bought it up is because I am so set on seeing it as a *gimme teh codez* question in disguise. But I am understanding of your "borderline" reasons. I guess in the end questions votes really don't mean anything. Unlike answers there isn't really a "most votes go to the top" system, because there isn't anything to go to the top of

Answer (score 35):

Stack Overflow's focus is shifting.

In the starter years, it was merely a "documentation simplification", because existing documentation and examples were flawed. Microsoft and Sun's documentation were too factual without too many examples (*"Method FooBar foos the bar."*, not mentioning what a bar is or why you would foo one), PHP's documentation was incomplete at best and the community responses to those sites were harmful to say the least. Forums didn't have voting, so it was *hard* to find decent code examples where caveats of said examples were explained properly.

Questions like *"How do I split a string?"*, *"How do I perform an HTTP request?"*, *"How does SQL group by work?"* were very welcome on Stack Overflow then.

When SO got to the state of where most of such basic questions were answered, the key point to asking a question became research. ["What have you tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) (http://www.whathaveyoutried.com). This is still true.

The first phase still isn't over as far as I'm concerned, lots of those "basic" or "reference" questions' answers still lack detail, explanations of caveats, links to sources and especially generality (lots of them are "too localized", which isn't a thing anymore). There's still lots of work to do there if Stack Overflow still wants to be a knowledge base.

Currently, adhering to the closing guidelines, a lot of the questions being asked are "unclear" (lack of detail of what the asker *exactly* wants to do, and whether one given approach is feasible and desirable) or "too broad" (asking too much at once, or asking for things that aren't properly explained in a paragraph or two). The tendency though is that such questions don't get closed, but answered - poorly. I say poorly because there's usually little interaction with the asker, but the answerer takes a few assumptions and answers as they see fit.

This causes answers to common questions to be spread out, making the case hard to research and, worse, hard to find authoritive, correct, well-explained answers. Here starts the problem I'm having with the current state of affairs: experts are a scarce resource, they can't find and answer each invocation of common questions, slowly [turning Stack Overflow into what it was specifically created to fight](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html): a collection of unfindable, unanswerable, uncontrollable, unverifyable and even incorrect questions and answers!

An abstract example: if you know you want to apply a certain type of authentication to a web application built in a certain framework, optionally running on a certain specific web server, or when you know your HTTP client is failing because it isn't sending cookies, it is *very easy* to find the proper answer. Concrete: [Basic authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144364/basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-5), [How to add cookies to WebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164275/how-to-add-cookies-to-webrequest). (I'll ignore the fact that for both questions many exact duplicates exist already).

The problem: this is all swell when you *know* what the problem is. Questions posted nowadays are being asked by people that *don't* know what they're doing or what the problem is. *"How to use authentication in MVC?"*, or *"Why does my web scraper not work?"*. Such questions get asked multiple times a day (and I'm sure your favorite tag has its own share of recurring questions), and answered too.

Yet list questions and too broad questions are forbidden (*"What ways of authentication exist for ASP.NET?"*, *"How to build a properly functioning web scraper?"*) and repetition of existing answers is rewarded (case in point: the question linked to by OP and its currently top-voted answer at 20 points that [doesn't add anything new to the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784663/linq-groupby-and-aggregate) - no offense meant, I see this often and sometimes do it too).

We need to create broader and better reference questions, like the question linked to here can be generalized. By building upon a good set of basic questions and proper answers that complement each other, we can work our way to a point where answering every single question becomes as easy as collecting links to reference questions and piecing them together with some explanatory text.

We need to work harder towards building this knowledge base, as opposed to Stack Overflow becoming (or continuing to be) an answering machine for *every* rehash of existing questions, as that machine will one day grind to a halt.

Comment: Well, you've got my vote for moderator this year! Oh, damn, we already did that.

Comment: @Josh ain't nobody got time for that. :P

Comment: I know the feeling...

Comment: _"We need to create broader and better reference questions"_ -- agreed, and IMHO this is why the question at hand is _not_ good. This particular question almost certainly already has a bunch of duplicates on SO in the first place, and really should have been voted closed on that basis. But beyond that, nothing in the question expands on the body of knowledge on SO, nor on MSDN where one can find an exhaustive presentation of everything you can do with LINQ. Instead, folks just wrote code for this person.

Answer (score 18):

Your personal upvote and downvote preferences are your own.  Unlike closing, deleting, answering or commenting, you do not have to justify why you up or downvote.

About the only rule is that you cannot target voting based on identity (which covers voting rings, sock puppet voting, revenge voting, and thank-you voting).

But you asked for opinions.  I've got plenty.

Here is a reason to upvote:

Would the question improve the site?

There are a number of ways a question can improve the site.

First, it could be a novel way to word an existing problem on the site, and you can close it as a duplicate of a good version of that question.

It could be a new question that is well enough worded that it can be searched for, and if found the answers will help the people who found it.

It could be a question that you, yourself, are curious about, and would love for it to be answered.

It could be a question that you think would generate good answers that you'd love to see.

It could be a question you'd love to answer.

Upvoting will tell others who browse the site that "this is the kind of question that should be asked".  Upvoting will encourage others to check out the question (and possibly answer it).  Upvoting may cause search engines to find the question rather than an alternative.

There are going to be similar reasons to downvote a question.

If something qualifies as both upvotable and downvotable, well, that is life.  You are going to have to either pick, or abstain.

Comment: All good points (from all answers too), I accept that it's really not that important overall and to go with what I feel. In this case I think I will keep my downvote as I value effort over "asking nicely". However, if the OP was to indicate that the reason they asked was to improve the site/community, and it wasn't actually a case that they couldn't resolve the issue themselves (or be bothered to) then I might be more accepting as I do generally agree it is a useful post and helpful  to others

Answer (score 15):

If you search on Google for 'linq query to merge distinct items' you get a fair bit of tat. This Q+A will probably rise to the top of Google's search results, and thus people in the future will find good, peer-reviewed answers when searching for solutions to this problem.

In the meantime, the askers and answerers get some extra rep, so everyone's happy.

I know it would be nice if everyone jumped through every hoop that we ask them to, but in the end, everyone benefits from questions like this. It is a fine line, but for me, this question is on the right side of it.

That said, of course it's your prerogative, and that's the other great thing about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

BoltClock, I see your point about the "give me the code" approach being annoying.  There's plenty of that opinion on SO.  A few points to consider:

- The OP may be new to that technology. So some grace from the rest of us may be warranted.
- The OP may have researched it, but just failed to include that in their post. I've done that for the sake of brevity. Or they may fail to include their research due to lack of time.
- Additionally, the OP may have researched it but failed to include the right keywords in their search terms to get the answer.  The scenario could be like this, "OP: How do I do Easy X?", "Answer: Did you try Y?", "OP: Doh! Forgot about that."
- The question may be well presented, which means it will be easy for future SO users to easily understand the problem and readily apply the solution. That's valuable as a public resource.
- The question may be composed in such a way that Google will index it in what some people may consider a more **naturally worded** way. This tends to happen more frequently for questions that get flagged as SO duplicates.

Since improved search-ability is a good thing on SO, I'd personally avoid down-voting a "give me the code" question that's well presented with good naturally searchable wording.

SO is for both professional and enthusiast programmers.  I'd expect a pro to research before asking.  I wouldn't expect an amateur, or someone new to a technology, to necessarily perform the research before asking a question.

Of course you can downvote for any reason, but that's my 2 cents.  Good question.

Comment: Experience with a certain technology, or programming in general, has no correlation with writing and research skills - though it is somewhat true that the least researched questions tend also to be the most poorly-written ones. I don't mind "give me the code" if the question doesn't frame itself that way - I do however mind "gimme teh codez" because those are low-effort posts all around, and usually not worth the time of a self-respecting user (exceptional reasons notwithstanding).

Comment: Personally I don't mind not including information in the question for the sake of brevity - so long as the OP states it upfront so readers can understand and help the OP reconcile both issues, because if the OP doesn't, then readers have no information to go on about the question at all. Lack of time on the other hand is just about one of the weakest possible excuses - users have all the time in the world to compose, draft, proofread and polish their questions as many times as they like before the initial submission. Questions posted under duress are highly unlikely to ever be good questions.

Comment: Point #3 is precisely why I don't consider "research effort" as the sole deciding factor in making or breaking a question. Not only is it the reason certain topics come up endlessly, but it is also often the reason we can't find suitable duplicates for even the most common topics (even when we think we *have* included the right keywords). Points #4 and #5 both lend themselves to this.

Comment: (FYI I'm just expanding my thoughts on this answer in response to it expanding on my comments - I could post a separate answer instead, but I figured I'd comment here so my responses are tied to this answer rather than getting lost among the rest of them.)

Comment: _“the OP may have researched it but failed to include the right keywords in their search terms”_ **Yes.**  In the past decade when I've been learning something completely new to me (Objective-C/Cocoa, Ruby/Rails, C#/.NET, Node.js) this has been a point of frustration again and again.  When learning something new, some people grasp the concepts better at first, and some people the specifics.  And trying to explain a problem in one toolkit with terminology from another can lead to… _unpopularness_ amongst more experienced devs.

Answer (score 4):

Research is useful to:

**Reduce duplication**. Sometimes all that is needed is the correct keyword to find a solution without posting on SO. Some research is likely to turn up prospective search terms. Apply these and prospective OP might not need to bother with posting the question. The solution may well be one on SO – hence not bothering with posting the question means one less duplicate on SO.

Ensure OP is aware of “**context**” – so hopefully will, for example, remember to mention “I am using version `x`” (rather than staying silent about which version) if researches have turned up a solution that works for `y` but not `x`. (Otherwise time and space may be wasted with an answer that works only for `y`.)

Serve as a “dummy run” (like **rubber duck**) – Could be as simple as capitalising MAC in the OP when a search beforehand seems to be turning up rather a lot of irrelevant references to Macintosh computers.

Related to the above -**widen horizons**. Research might indicate a lot of similar issues with databases on remote servers but if OP’s instance is on a local server maybe that fact will be mentioned in the first attempt at asking the question on SO.

HOWEVER

It is not necessary to require prospective OP’s to have researched say “double unary operator” if their question is like [What — does in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286197/what-does-in-excel). Key `--` into Google as a search term and the result is *Your search - -- - did not match any documents. Suggestions:
•   Try different keywords.*
If the question is specific and clear and not one that has been asked, in various forms, hundreds of times before on SO and thousands of times elsewhere on the web there is **no need to demonstrate research** (just don't demonstrate that you have **not** researched). The downvote popup mentions “does not show any research effort” and though it would be highly presumptuous of me to twist those words I think the intent might be closer to “demonstrates no research effort”. The (subtle) difference being between just googling the question Title being effective in finding lots of hits to exactly the right answer, and a question that shows the OP has at least made some attempt to think about the problem, and what is relevant to describe it, before rushing in to print.

Bear in mind that SO is mainly for non-users. People who may never have heard of SO before but end up here just from keying a search term and hitting Enter. These are the people we are trying to help as much as or more than users. Consider how much effort *they* have put in to asking a question (or answering!) on SO before downvoting those that do post a not-quite-perfect question here.

The crux of the matter is really “would a modicum of research have made big difference?” Personally, I don’t want questions prefixed with “I have spent four hours searching…”, “I have tried this formula …” (whose functions are inappropriate and whose syntax is wildly out anyway), “I tried this code I found on the web …” (where clearly written for a completely different purpose) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There are some questions where you don't know where you need to start or what to look for. The question exampled feels like that type. He knows what he wants, but is too unfamiliar with the language or even the particular part of the language to know what he can do.

I had similar issues myself when I started using iOS's Core Data and simply didn't know enough SQL commands to get the information I needed. I didn't know where to start or what I needed to do. Thanks to some answers, I was able to get a bearing and got to a point where I could research myself and find the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I usually treat the `research effort` criterion as two separate and equal questions:

- has the author put significant effort into understanding **what the problem is**?  Did they bother to read the stdout/stderr?  If an error message mentions a line number, did they at least reread that line in the code and try to imagine what the error might mean?  Did they try other inputs?  Did they try narrowing down their input to reduce the problem?  Did they try narrowing down their *code* to reduce the problem?
- has the author put significant effort into trying to **solve the problem** before turning to StackOverflow?  Did they run their code more than once?  (Or at all?)  Did they Read The Friendly Manual?  Did they Google?  Did they read the error message and try something else in response to it (even if they didn't really know what they were doing)?

If the answer to either of these is "yes", then I'll rarely downvote a question even if the answer to the other is clearly "no".  In fact, nowadays it's so rare to find any effort *at all* in questions that fulfilling either of the above criteria is usually enough to get an *upvote* from me.  Of course, that may just be the PTSD (Post Triage-Queue Stress Disorder) talking ...

Answer (score -1):

I would probably have downvoted it. The only value a question like this has for StackOverflow is more content and more traffic which is better for the [business model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255491/what-is-stack-overflows-source-of-income).

The knowledge base that is SO doesn't profit much from questions like this, because the information can be found easily, including on SO. So, future visitors who would do research, probably would have found the info in one of the other sources, while those who do not research won't find any of the sources at all. I think the huge load of questions like this may even cannibalize the find-ability of the more useful questions.

To be fair, I often do a little check first. Before downvoting a seemingly non-well-researched question, I search for the specific wording OP uses. Maybe that wording doesn't give many useful results, in which case asking a new question may be justified if you don't know what other terms to look for. But if I search for the title or a core sentence or terminology from the question, and that already gives me a bunch of answers, then I will downvote immediately.

Comment: "The only value a question like this has for StackOverflow is more traffic and therefor a better business model." wat

Comment: _"I think the huge load of questions like this may even cannibalize the find-ability of the more useful questions."_ - my point exactly.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, that sentence of mine could do with better grammar. Still, traffic == income, I think. But it's not the point. The *real* point is that although this question may be good for whatever, it is not good for the quality of the knowledge base. If this message is lost due to bad grammar in my answer, please read CodeCaster's, who has put to words similar thoughts much more eloquently.