# How is this question a good example of "This question shows research effort..."?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, upvotes

> ***TL;DR :: This post is not about "why not downvote", rather it is about "Why upvote"?***

I have researched a few answers here is MSO to get answer of the above question, like

- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2173917)
- [Does a well explained question nullify a “no research effort” downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291081/2173917)
- [Upvoting for reasons other than “showing research and effort”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308352/2173917)

and what I've understood from all the answers is that, even if the question is "clear and explained" with MCVE (*really appreciate that part*), there *must* be a minimum visible research effort from the OP to make the question welcome here.

Now, [when I see 19 (+19/-3) of the fellow users going opposite to my understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34488559/2173917), I have to ask, am I missing something in the basic understanding for a ***"good question"***?

*P.S 1 - I do not have any issues with the current voting pattern, but the problem maybe, somehow, directly or indirectly we're **neglecting the tooltips for the voting buttons** and we may end up encouraging new members from asking similar questions with no research effort, whatsoever.*

*P.S 2 - As per my understanding, I left a comment below the question stating the same point I mentioned here, but got no response from the OP as any edit.*

Comment: People can vote however what they want. If I find the question interesting or useful I may well upvote it regardless of research effort. As long as the question is answerable I personally regard that as low priority in my assessment. Whether the OP makes a "visible" research effort or not is irrelevant to future readers.

Comment: Hmm, you have 15 highly upvoted answers in the [language-lawyer] tag.  A tag that would not exist if every [c] or [c++] programmer would be capable of reading and understanding the spec.  Few do, nobody expects them to.  Yes, it gets pretty boring after a while, odds you'll get help getting rid of them are rather low.

Comment: IMO that question was ALMOST good, if it had been about explaining the source of the warning/error rather than degrading it to a comparison of standards between two different languages which is simply unproductive. Curiosity killed the question.

Answer (score 9):

In an ideal world, questions would be upvoted if they were insightful, well-researched, well-phrased, and generally interesting. Similarly, questions would be downvoted if they lacked research effort or were generally unhelpful. Unfortunately, that is simply not how the Stack Overflow of 2016 works.

I downvote most questions because when I see them, I vomit a little in my mouth. They are questions with 200 lines of code, broken English, a question that has been asked dozens of times, and are simply looking for a code snippet to copy and paste into their program to make it work. No effort was made to debug the problem before turning to Stack Overflow, and no attempt was made to communicate the thought process behind the code. It’s the Q&A equivalent of throwing garbage on the ground, knowing somebody else will eventually pick it up.

So when a question comes along that *doesn’t* make me want to throttle the poster through my computer screen, I have to take a step back and think for a moment: is this the legendary “good question”? Is such a thing even *possible*?

Considering “just gimme the code” questions are routinely upvoted, and frequently fade into obscurity with a positive score, it’s no small wonder that questions that just so much as manage to formulate a coherent, answerable question are upvoted.

Okay, okay, enough with the generalizations: what about the question you linked? Well, frankly, it’s a pretty good question. I didn’t upvote it, but I certainly wouldn’t downvote it. Why?

1. It’s well-phrased and clear. It asks an understandable, answerable question (even if the scope is a tiny bit broad).
2. It provides minimal, coherent code snippets that help to illustrate the problem.
3. The question itself is interesting! I personally find “Why is C different from C++ in this regard?” questions to be excessively stupid—they’re not much different from asking “Why is C different from Haskell?”, really—but they tend to be accepted because they are related languages, both historically and nominally. That said, the behavior here is subtle, and it’s often fun to see how standards dictate such different behavior from minute differences in wording.
4. Similar to the above, the question itself isn’t trivial. C and C++ are notoriously complicated languages (okay, well, C++ is), and reading the standard is no easy feat. Some people enjoy that sort of thing, though, and the question is absolutely good enough to give those people the information they need.

This question is not a paragon of quality, and it certainly isn’t terribly useful to future readers. But at this point, the vast majority of questions on Stack Overflow don’t fit into that bucket. This question may not be practically useful, but I found it to be intriguing and a legitimate curiosity; that is, I enjoyed reading the question and its answer. It’s a fun question without being too silly.

And, well, [votes are subjective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/465378). There are no real rules as to how you use your votes, short of abusing the system. People will vote on things as they see fit, which introduces a sort of inherent relativism in voting. Prescriptivism in votes won’t get anyone anywhere: the system simply isn’t designed with that goal in mind. Feel free to downvote whatever you don’t like, and leave comments when you think things are unfairly voted upon.

Asking questions about this sort of thing on Meta is healthy, of course, but I think this particular topic is relatively solved. I would imagine a significant majority of voters don’t even read Meta. There are bigger (and more accessible) fish to fry.

Comment: Great answer! At first I was feeling like the OP (and I think their comment on the question in question is still justified). But after reading your answer I completely agree with you. On SO there are even posts with several thousand upvotes. But are they necessarily a thousand times better than posts with just a few upvotes? Certainly not. But does this do any harm? I don't think so. You are right, there is more important clean-up work to do.